# Error in opening RAD 8.5 Deployment Descriptor

Tags: ibm-rad

```
The deployment information cannot be loaded successfully. You cannot make any changes to the deployment page. 
Ensure that a webSphere server runtime has been defined with the correct WebSphere installation directory.
Ensure that a valid WebSphere Server profile has been defined under the selected WebSphere runtime.
```

I checked all the possible ways to debug the issue, can some one let me know where issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I deleted the server, restarted RAD, recreated the server and everything is fine now.
I hope this trick will be useful also for the next viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the existing profiles in Preferences->Server->Web Sphere Application Server, here see if there are any read only profiles which are not used . Delete them the problem will be solved.

Even I faced similar problem. Thanks